# Can I format timestamp dates from Mongoose and display in React JSX?

Tags: reactjs, date, mongoose, format

I am using timestamps in Mongoose to create 'createdAt' and 'updatedAt' properties on each data item object. Is it possible to take these dates and format and display them in React? I keep trying with date-fns and I just get invalid date errors.

The time looks like the following in my db: 'createdAt 2023-11-02T02:55:54.488+00:00', but looks like this in my code: 'createdAt:  1698893754488'.

I'm not finding much help in the Mongoose docs so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What you can try:

Where you are showing your `createAt` date, you can do like this:

const date = new Date(createdAt);

`<div>{date}</div>`

So, `new Date()` would help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is normal,
your time in Interger is simply your date in linux format
you can try online for an exemple go to [Dan's Tool](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/)

so in your case the : 1698893754488

is equal to : GMT: Thursday 2 November 2023 02:55:54.488

So you can import [Moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/) and only create a new [Moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/) date
Or using simply the [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

And after you can parse a good date format